# Find certain pattern in string in redshift with regexp

Tags: regex, amazon-redshift

In redshift, I need to use sql to query through a column(column type varchar):
example:
`{"partner_1":"0,1,2,3","partner_33":"0,1"}` and many variations of.

But the rows I want to actually get in my WHERE clause is only "partner_1": "<and if one of the values is 1>"

So, for example I would collect this row:`{"partner_1":"0,1,2,3","partner_33":"0,1"}` but not this: `{"partner_1":"0","partner_33":"0,1"}` .

I found a solution, which is not really an optimal one, would appreciate any input.  This is what I use now:

```
WHERE split_part(<column_name>,'"partner_1":',2) ilike '%1%'
```

but if there is a row that has this: `{"partner_1":"0","partner_33":"0,1"}` the above clause will get this row too, which I don't want.

I would appreciate anyone who can help here.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to split_part through the field.  Created a view in redshift with

split_part(split_part(split_part(<column_name>, 'partner_1":"',2),'","',1),'"',1) as partner_1

And in the query pick up the rows where the column in view like '%1%'